Do I have a neutral wire available for a smart switch?
I am hoping to replace the switch on the right with a smart switch. Most of the smart switch requires neutral wire. However, looking at my box here, I can't tell if I have a neutral wire. Left switch controls couple of outlets and right switch controls an exterior light.
The picture shows the current setup. I tried installing a smart switch with A as neutral but it didn't work (capped off B). No power went to the smart switch and switch on the left also quit working.
Does this mean I don't have a neutral wire?


"This one has voltage" ... to what?

FYI you need two more bare (or green) wires in the G/H wire nut, running to each switch to ground them.

Yes you do have it, it is the left cable (A,B)

"I tried installing a smart switch with A as neutral but it didn't work (capped off B)." – Are you saying that you disconnected A and B from each other? Why did you do that? They're connected for a reason.

No, for the purposes of installing a smart switch to replace the switch on the right, you don't have a neutral. I'll explain.
There is a neutral for the circuit on the left. But the circuit on the right is independent of the circuit on the left where the neutral is found. The one on the right is just a switch loop. There are two circuits sharing this box - this is not a problem, but it can be confusing.
Electric code requires that supply and return (hot and neutral, or out-of-phase hots) must be matched and must run in the same conduit or cable. If you power a smart switch using the hot of the switch loop on the right and the neutral of whatever-it-is circuit on the left, then the switch will be powered between hot in one cable and neutral in another cable. This is a code violation. It's also unsafe.
Now.. all hope might not be lost. It might be possible to re-work the wiring so that the light of the switch on the right is powered by the left-side circuit. In that case your smart switch neutral and hot would connect to the incoming cable on the left; the white-taped-black of the one on the right would have the tape removed and become neutral, and the black on the right would continue to be switched hot. You'd have to get into the junction box at the other end of the cable - at the exterior light, I presume - and make corresponding changes to disconnect from the circuit that previously powered the lights. That might or might not be feasible. If you want to explore that further with us it'll be best to gather information from that junction box and post a new question.

Another possible option: there are some smart switches that are listed to use ground to return their very tiny amount of self-power, instead of a neutral.

Thank you so much! I'll look into the possibility of rewiring them but most likely I'll just buy a smart switch that doesn't require neutral wire.

Left: Supply at switch - neutral present
You have an incoming home run on the left switch (A and D). A is your neutral there. B is the return from the load (light). This neutral is not available to the right-hand switch.
Right: Supply at light - neutral not present
On the right, F seems to be your incoming hot (passing through the light box), which is why it's a white wire marked black. F is switched hot back to the load. No, you can't share the neutral from the other cable.
H appears to just be ground for that cable.
